# How to convert 4band RGB/A GeoTiff to 1band Gray GeoTiif?

Tags: gdal, dem, slope, hillshade

I'm creating slopeshade images from a DEM. What I'm doing is:

```
gdaldem slope -alg Horn -s 1 -compute_edges -co BIGTIFF=YES in.tif /vsistdout/ | \
    gdaldem color-relief -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW /vsistdin/ slope.txt out.tif
```

but the file generated has 4 bands, RGBA, while I actually need only one. I tried further filtering with:

```
gdal_translate -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=LZW -b 1 out.tif out_1band.tif
```

but `gdalinfo` says band 1 is red, not gray, as the output of `gdaldem hillshade`:

```
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red   vs
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

This confirms the fact that gdal can generate the file I want, just not with the tool I'm using.

For info, I'm using `mapnik` to render this, and it's treating the file as if it were pure white (while qGIS properly renders it as geryscale; maybe the bug is in `mapnik`?). `mapnik` handles the 1band hillshade file with no problem.

I could do more fine grained things in Python if needed, bur I have no idea how to start.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why not stay with the RGB if it works? Because the dataset I'm using is huge (worldwide) but I don't have much resources in terms of disk space and memory.

Comment: Could you explain what is the benefit of your method compared with the hillshade mode? Color-relief is obviously designed to give a colored result which means that some tricks or post-processing will be needed.

Comment: tis is for slope shade, not hill shade. I mention hillshade because it can generate a 1band gray file that works with `mapnik`. `slope.txt` has white for 0 degrees and black for 90.

Comment: If the problem is in changing the color interpretation from red to gray you can use gdal_edit for that.

Comment: `gdal_edit` only seems to have options for R, G, B, A or undefined: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html

Comment: I would try with undefined. Your single band red image is a bit weird if not buggy. The metadata seems to be in GDAL metadata tag `Tag 42112: <GDALMetadata>  <Item name="COLORINTERP" sample="0" role="colorinterp">Red</Item>` You can get rid of it if you write a baseline tiff but then you lose also georeferencing.

Comment: The tag stays even in a baseline tiff. I would ask from the gdal-dev mailing list what to do and if there is some bug involved.

Comment: A GDAL developer has obviously seen this discussion and made some improvements to gdal_edit https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/41385 and gdal_translate  https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/41386

Answer (score 4):

Given a grayscale conversion algorithm, `gdal_calc` is able to convert an RGB(A) GeoTIFF to a grayscale one (Credits to [Jukka Rahkonen](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/RGB-to-Grayscale-td5201726.html)).
For instance:

```
gdal_calc.py -R input.tif --R_band=1 -G input.tif --G_band=2 -B input.tif --B_band=3 --outfile=result.tif --calc="R*0.2989+G*0.5870+B*0.1140"
```

We can choose among different grayscale conversion algorithms (Source: http://www.tannerhelland.com/3643/grayscale-image-algorithm-vb6/), replacing only the formula:

Average

```
--calc="(R+G+B)/3"
```

Image processors (Photoshop, GIMP)

```
--calc="R*0.3+G*0.59+B*0.11"
```

BT.709 recommendation (ITU-R)

```
--calc="R*0.2126+G*0.7152+B*0.0722"
```

BT.601 recommendation

```
--calc="R*0.299+G*0.587+B*0.114"
```

Desaturation

```
--calc="(maximum(maximum(R,G),B)+minimum(minimum(R,G),B))/2"
```

Minimum decomposition

```
--calc="minimum(minimum(R,G),B)"
```

Maximum decomposition

```
--calc="maximum(maximum(R,G),B)"
```

etc.

Comment: Just a warning/note that if the output already exists and it's multi-band, and you don't specify `--overwrite`, then this will retain the multiple bands.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not yet released, but if you're like me, you can compile it yourself.

I asked the same question in the `#gdal` IRC channel and Even Rouault hacked a little in the source code and:

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/75488db0f4931f14721afa4f6ef3f06c7be31916

So now I can do `gdal_edit.py -colorinterp_1 gray foo.tif` and that's it. As per Even, this will be released in `gdal-2.3` in the near future.

Comment: This changes the metadata color interpretation hint for the specified band(s) but does not collapse a 3 or more band image into a single band image. So it's useful and good to know (+1 for that) but doesn't address everything in the Q.

Comment: But I think the OP has had the same issue I had: one grayscale TIFF with 3-4 bands (RGB[A]), when actually one is enough (after all, all the bands have exactly the same info if it's really gray scale). I think my original issue (and probably OP's) was that one of gdal's tools (probably `gdaldem slope` or `hillshade`) produces such a TIFF.